# get-pip.py ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 0] Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I built python 2.7.11 from source and now I am attempting to get pip using the `get-pip.py`. It actually does install `pip.exe` in my Scripts directory of the python install, and also the pip module in the site-packages, but at the end of the install it says the error:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 0] Error`

I can't install any packages with it because it says the same error as well.

It's not very descriptive on what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Have you tried `python get-pip.py`? Also, since you have 2.7.11 and installed it from source you must have to have pip already installed. Try upgrading it first.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Also pip does not come with python 2.7.11 when building from source.

Comment: You can get the `get-pip.py` from this link : https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run that from your Python Interpreter.

Comment: As I've said I already have done this step. It results in the error message above.

Comment: I can only think of it being an environment disruption. Why are you building it from source though?